# Align equations

Tags: equations

I have to put three equations. I am using the following code:

```
\begin{gather}
m_{1,1}^i = \sum (x - \bar{x}^i) (y - \bar{y}^i)\text{,} \\
m_{2,0}^i = \sum (x - \bar{x}^i)^2 \text{ and} \\
m_{0,2}^i = \sum (y - \bar{y}^i)^2 \text{ } \forall  \text{ } n(x,y) \in G_i
\end{gather}
```

**What I am getting:**

[image]

**What I need:**

[image]

**Question:** How can I align the left starting of all the three equations?

Comment: You need ampersands :) and the align environment...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about them. Could you please post an example.

Comment: See the amsmath manual, might also want to look up the mathmode doc on ctan, or even any decent latex intro

Comment: One good example is [posted here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A).

Comment: I used `\begin{alignat}{2} ...... \end{alignat}` .....but it aligned the right side. Still searching.

Comment: not `alignat`, but `align` and put an `&` before the `=` sign in each equation.  see the `amsmath` users guide -- `texdoc amsmath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align` can be found in the [amsmath guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf). Note that the ampersands define what to align. In this situation, put & before the "=" of each equation.

```
\begin{align}
 m_{1,1}^i &= \sum (x - \bar{x}^i) (y - \bar{y}^i)\text{,} \\
 m_{2,0}^i &= \sum (x - \bar{x}^i)^2 \text{ and} \\
 m_{0,2}^i &= \sum (y - \bar{y}^i)^2 \text{ } \forall  \text{ } n(x,y) \in G_i
\end{align}
```