# align three equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

What wrong with that?

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    {v}_{sa}=m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}cos(\omega_{1}t)\\
    {v}_{sb}=m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}cos(\omega_{1}t -\frac{2\pi}{3})\\
    {v}_{sn}=m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}cos(\omega_{1}t +\frac{2\pi}{3})\\
    \label{current_rel1}
\end{eqnarray}
```

I want to get  v<sub>sa</sub> ... v<sub>sb</sub> ... v<sub>sn</sub>:

```
 V_sa=...
 V_sb=...
 V_sn=...
```

Someone can help solving that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have specified no alignment points. Anyway, `eqnarray` is deprecated and gives bad spacing. Replace it with the `align` environment, from `amsmath`.

Comment: Generally the advice is to use the `align` environment from [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) rather than `eqnarray` ([eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/106162)), in order to specify alignment points you need to place `&` at the alignment points, one `&` when using `align` and two when using `eqnarray`.  See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277511/106162) for an example with `align`.

Comment: You should definitely replace `cos` with `\cos`. Also, I know of no advantage to having `{v}_{sa}` instead of just `v_{sa}`

Comment: great,That works.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe one of these is what you  want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    v_{sa} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos(\omega_{1}t) \\
    v_{sb} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos\Bigl(\omega_{1}t -\frac{2π}{3}\Bigr) \\
    v_{sn} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos\Bigl(\omega_{1}t +\frac{2π}{3}\Bigr)
    \label{current_rel1}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

  \begin{align}
    v_{sa} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos(\omega_{1}t) \label{current_rel2} \\
    v_{sb} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos\Bigl(\omega_{1}t -\frac{2π}{3}\Bigr) \label{current_rel3} \\
    v_{sn} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos\Bigl(\omega_{1}t +\frac{2π}{3}\Bigr)
    \label{current_rel4}
  \end{align}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    v_{sa} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos(\omega_{1}t) \label{current_rel1a} \\
    v_{sb} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos\Bigl(\omega_{1}t -\frac{2π}{3}\Bigr) \label{current_rel1b} \\
    v_{sn} & =m_{a}\frac{V_{d}}{2}\cos\Bigl(\omega_{1}t +\frac{2π}{3}\Bigr)
    \label{current_rel1c}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The original code has all three equations numbered. Can you add the alternative code for that?

Comment: @egreg: I'll add it, but there was only one label, from which I inferred it was meant as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use the `eqnarray` environment: It's badly deprecated. [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) Instead of `eqnarray`, use the `align` environment that's provided by the `amsmath` package. See the posting [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) for more information on this subject.
- Don't forget to provide alignment points. (Your current code needs `&=&` instead of just `=`.) For the `align` environment, place `&` before `=` in order to achieve alignment on the `=` symbols.
- Write `\cos` instead of `cos` to get the term to behave like a math operator.
- Either create larger parentheses around the arguments of `\cos` or use smaller fractions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    v_{sa}&=\tfrac{1}{2}m_{a}V_d\cos(\omega_{1}t)\\
    v_{sb}&=\tfrac{1}{2}m_{a}V_d\cos(\omega_{1}t -\tfrac{2}{3}\pi)\\
    v_{sn}&=\tfrac{1}{2}m_{a}V_d\cos(\omega_{1}t +\tfrac{2}{3}\pi) \label{current_rel1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```